# how to ignore required column on update entity framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a class named `Client` with `Id`, `Name` and `Password` required.

I'm trying to update the name of the client without changing the password ( I don't want to query the `Client` before the update to get the password and set it again ).

I have this code inside the `Client.Update()` method:

```
db.Entry<Client>(this).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(this).Property(q => q.Password).IsModified = false;
db.SaveChanges(); //gives exception and complains that password was not set
```

I can make it work using this code before `SaveChanges` but i want to know of there's another way.

```
 db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

I'm using asp.net mvc 5.2.2 with entity framework 6.1.1.

Comment: Have you tried to only set each property as Modified?  I don't think you can say the object is modified and then specify that only one property isn't.

Comment: @ErikPhilips even when i attach the object to the context, i've got the same exception about the password was not set.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that before you send a `Client` object to the UI you first erase the password. Which is wise, so now it can't be sniffed out.

But when you want to save the client, EF's validation spots an empty required property and there's your catch-22. "Fixing" this by disabling validation is possible, but potentially harmful, because you may miss other validations.

Re-fetching the client from the database and modify its name only is a way to do this safely, but if you don't want this extra database round trip you could apply *table splitting*.

You can split the client table into two classes, e.g. these:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SensitiveClientData SensitiveClientData { get; set; }
}

public class SensitiveClientData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have to tell EF that both classes map to one table. This is how to do this (in the `DbContext`-derived context):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.SensitiveClientData)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().ToTable("Client");
    modelBuilder.Entity<SensitiveClientData>().ToTable("Client");
}
```

This makes creating a client a bit more complex:

```
var client = db.Clients.Create();
client.Name = "Donald Duck";
client.SensitiveClientData = new SensitiveClientData { Password = "goofy1" };

db.Clients.Add(client);

db.SaveChanges();
```

But now you can fetch a client without `Include()`-ing its `SensitiveClientData`, modify its name and save it without ever having had its password.